# How to compile TSX to template literals at build time?

Tags: typescript, jsx, tsconfig

Considering a simple pure SSR Node.js project using TypeScript.
Currently my template engine is through *template literals* using a library called `nanohtml`.

```
// Some .ts file 
import html from 'nanohtml'
export const template = (variable) => html`<p>Hello ${variable}</p>`

// Somewhere (in a .ts file)
res.send( template("world").toString() )
```

However, I'd like to minimize the number of libraries/dependencies **in production** and use libraries I already have (TypeScript in this case) more efficiently.

Is it then possible to use JSX-like syntax (?) that compiles into JS file and template literal (ditching `nanohtml`). And what would be the config in `tsconfig.json`?

```
// Example - Some .tsx file with NO nanohtml lib
export const template = (variable) => <p>Hello ${variable}</p>       // option 1
export const template = (variable) => jsx`<p>Hello ${variable}</p>`  // or option 2
....
```

Comment: Are you making static or dynamic?

Comment: @Dimava What do you mean (here) by static or dynamic?